# Get last n elements of list from current index

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this : `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` and I want to extract the previous 'n' elements from a particular index.

For eg: If I take index 7, I have the element 8 in it. And for `n = 3`, I want to get the previous 3 elements starting backwards from index 7. The result would be `[5, 6, 7]`.

I am not able to come up with a slicing formula to get this. Could someone please help me?

Comment: `l[index-n:index]` with `index=7` in this case!?

Answer (score 2):

The code is very straight forward:

```
l = [i for i in range(1,15)]
n = 3
index = 7
print(l[index-n:index])
```

The Output:

```
[5, 6, 7]
```